# Best vdW correction functional for transition metal dichalcogenides

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, ab-initio-calculations, dispersion-correction, dichalcogenides

For relaxation of transition metal dichalcogenides (e.g.: WS2) using the VASP code, what is the best choice for vdW correction method (e.g.: DFT-D2, DFT-D3 or optB88-vdW) that can give you good results ?

Comment: [This](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1120/88) might be helpful

Comment: Also related (in addition to the one Thomas linked): https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/63/5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DFT-D2 is simple and reliable. I've used DFT-D2 for most of my worked on 2D materials but I do I have to caution you that I have not specifically work on TMGs. You can test out the results you obtain from both DFT-D2 and DFT-D3 and compare them. Another idea is to look at literature. There is a labyrinth of data on TMGs and you can look under the 'methods' section of the papers.

This also depends on the kind of functional you use in KS-DFT. If you're using LDA, it's not practical to use vdw corrections because LDA already over-binds and using a vdw correction makes it only worse. If you're using PBE for example, it should be fine.

Comment: I'll tack on a couple of relevant papers here: ["Are we van der Waals ready"](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0953-8984/24/42/424218), ["van der Waals density functional made accurate"](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.89.121103).